# recode several variables placed in a vector in a column

Tags: r

I want to know how to recode several variables placed in a vector in a column, I put an example of my code.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  "num" = 1:5, 
  "letter" = c("a", "b", "c", "d" , "e"))

vector<-c("a","c")

df<-df %>% mutate(letter=recode(letter,vector="no"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `recode` doesn't take vector arguments. Instead of `recode` you can try a simple `if_else` statement like this:

```
df<-df %>% mutate(letter= if_else(letter %in% vector, 'no', letter))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the values of `letter` for `vector` values using `%in%` -

```
df$letter[df$letter %in% vector] <- 'no'
df

#  num letter
#1   1     no
#2   2      b
#3   3     no
#4   4      d
#5   5      e
```

Or in `data.table` -

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[letter %in% vector, letter := 'no']
df
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is good to know options